# How to save image in folder with difference name image from value base64 (Ex: image001,image002,dst) in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, filepath

This is my coding in webservice

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public void Base64ToImage(string imagestr)
    {

        DbAccessConnection conn = getActiveConnection();
        try
        {
            beginTransaction(conn);

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagestr);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                Image pic = Image.FromStream(ms);
                pic.Save("C:/image/image001.jpg");
            }

            commitTransaction(conn);
            Responder.writeResponse(true, "Sucess Convert Base64 String To Image");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rollbackTransaction(conn);
            Responder.writeResponse(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I want when insert a value base64 in web service it is create automatic file name with image001.jpg next when i input again value base64 it is create image002.jpg. Could you help how to fix it ?

Comment: You can be used GUID For Image name that will be always Uniq

Answer (score 0):

Collect file names in the server and extract the biggest number based on pattern, continue the serial number from that.

```
var max = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\...\imgs").Select(file => 
    int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Replace("image", ""))).Max();
string newFileName = $"image{max + 1:000}";
```

Or change the pattern to something that is no duplication like hash value.
Or record the last upload in DB.